# elasticsearch - "range" and "terms" together is not possible?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to run this `_search` query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "created_time": {
                "gt": "now-24h"
            }
        },
        "terms": {
            "from_id": [
                "144458",
                "112275"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But it returns this error:

```
{
    error: SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed; shardFailures {[GAIodkFdTI-mHRS2_IE-JQ][content][0]: SearchParseException[[content][0]: query[created_time:{1409011409797 TO *]],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"range":{"created_time":{"gt":"now-24h"}},"terms":{"from_id":["144458","112275"]}}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_OBJECT "terms"]; }]
    status: 400
}
```

If I remove `range` block or `terms` block, it works fine. They don't work only when trying together.

Is this a problem with elasticsearch? Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need a boolean query. You can't place two queries under the same "query" key.

If you want to AND both queries, then this should work:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "created_time": {
                            "gt": "now-24h"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "from_id": [
                            "144458",
                            "112275"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```